# How to sort values coming from bean using hasmap in java

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

Hi everyone i am new here and i would like your help on this task, i dont have much experience working with HashMap

Actually i am receiving this String with the next value

> String value1             = "DA45:1|DA33:2|DA25:3";

actually i have

```
Map<Integer, String> value1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

I need to parse these data and generating the map such that priority will be key and device name will be value for example :

key1 ----- > DA45

key2 ----->  DA33

key3 -----> DA25

please notice that i need to split ":","the number" and pipe

thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: Do you really care about order?? if you do, then use `TreeMap` and you might need to use a `Comparator` to enforce the order you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        String value1 = "DA45:1|DA33:2|DA25:3";
        String[] x = value1.split("\\|");
        Integer key;
        String value;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            String[] y = x[i].split(":");
            value = y[0];
            key = Integer.parseInt(y[1]);
            map.put(key, value);
        }


    }
}
```

In the end of this code snippet, the map will be fullfiled by your information.

Please choose better names for this variables, it is just an example.